# get the_title_attribute by id

Tags: permalinks, id, get-the-title

I'm creating a list with a few permalinks which I call to with `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>" title="...`. And for the title I want to call `the_title_attribute()`. But it seems it can only be called within a loop, and not by id. How do I correctly get a title attribute?

*Note: The reason I want to use `the_title_attributes();` is because I use html tags within some of my titles.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey just look in code and it also support fourth parameter `post`

```
global $post;    
the_title_attribute(array('post'=>$post));//post object
```

or

```
global $post;
the_title_attribute(array('post'=>$post->ID));//post id
```

so you can use it like

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(array('post'=>$id)); ?>"> //where $id is post id
```

**Important Link**

[the_title_attribute](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post-template.php#L71)

Comment: The fourth parameter should be used like this: `the_title_attribute( array( 'post' => get_post( $id ) ) );`

Comment: @iEmanuele hey buddy it also support post id.so we can pass post id to `post` parameter.please see on code of [the_title_attribute](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post-template.php#L71)

Comment: yeah it is true, who knows why, but I thought that the id outside the loop was not of the same post : )

Comment: Nice guys! This works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
get_the_title($ID);
```

to get title by id later you can add html tags like ..

```
$title_before = " // your html tags";

$title_after = "// your html tags";

$new_title = $title_before .''.get_the_title($ID).''.$title_after;
```